# Writing 2d int Array to file JAVA

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

It's been awhile since I've created and written to a file.  I've created the file and I've written to it but I get some weird characters.  The only numbers that should be in the file are -1, 0, and 1.

Now I get the numbers I need, but I need them to displayed as a 2d array in the text file.

Example:

```
     -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
     -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
     -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Please help

```
public void saveFile()
{
   String save = "Testing";
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);


    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            FileWriter bw = new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile()+".txt");

            for(int row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++)
           {
               for(int col =0; col < gameArray[row].length; col++)
               {
                  bw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]));
               }
           }
            bw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: The data is being written: however, *you are writing it as binary data*.

Comment: It's unclear what you *actually need*. If you want a text file that contains the textual values of the `int`s then you need to convert to a `String`. If not, then you can use a `DataOutputStream` to write the 4-byte `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use a `BufferedWriter` instead as it is easier.

> Writes text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as
>   to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and
>   strings.

Also, you do not need to append a `.txt`, AFAIK, because `JFileChooser` will return the full name.

**SSCCE:**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content,0,content.length());
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

taken from Mykong.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-) of `write(int c)` method

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

In other words you are passing index of character from Unicode table.

What you probably need is

```
fw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]));
```

which will first convert your integer to String and write its characters.

Also consider wrapping your writer with `PrintWriter` which has methods like `print`, `println` (similar to System.out) so you could just use

```
fw.print(gameArray[row][col]);
```

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-java.lang.String-

Comment: Failing on my part. :|

Comment: So when you write to files, they're automatically stored as Strings within the file?

Comment: @user2906074 Purpose of `Writers` is writing characters. If you are interested in writing bytes then you should use `Streams`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29), `write` with an integer argument writes a single character. I guess your `gameArray` has integer elements.

Convert the elements to a string and also take care to add a space between the numbers. Something like

```
fw.write(" " + gameArray[row][col]);
```

will work.

Comment: @user2864740 Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @user2864740: by wrapping the FileWriter into a PrintWriter, and using its various print() methods.

Comment: @JBNizet or just a `PrintWriter` and avoid the wrapping hassle? :)